# How do I create a navigation link between records in the same ms Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016, record-linkage

I'm new to Access and am having trouble finding a solution to this.
I have a FORM as a UI and need to make it easy to navigate to related records within the same form. Basically, if this record is related to that record I want to show it in a field and have the user go to that record by clicking on the field. The related records' IDs do not need to be stored in the underlying table, but they can be if needed. (Only one form and one table is involved.)
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How are the records related between each other?

Comment: They are records of crews and often the crews change names or tax IDs and I need to have a way to jump to their previous info/record. I have a 3-letter ID field that I was hoping I could make a link so that, when looking at one record and seeing that there is a related one, I could click and jump to the related one.